# Dynamically populate a Material UI Select Component, depending on other states

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, material-ui, state

I'm currently stuck with the following scenario.
I have two select components from Material-UI.

Select component one contains car brands, component two contains car models.

**Desired behaviour**

1. The car brands get fetched from the server and the list for Select "brands" gets populated.
2. Select "models" is still disabled, until a brand is selected.
3. Brand gets selected, client is fetching all models from this brand from server
4. Options for the Select 'models' get populated and the component becomes enabled

I store the fetched brand in a redux state.
I store the fetched model in a redux state.
I store the selected brand and model in a redux state.

```
{
 brand:{
  brands:{  
    brands:[
      {
       _id: 1,
       name: "vw"
      },
      {
       _id: 2,
       name: "bmw"
      }
    ]
  }
 },
 data:{
   form: {
      brandId: '',
      modelId: '',
      errors: {}
    },
    models:{}
 }
}
```

redux-states

**Current behaviour**

1. Car makers get fetched from server and the options for Select component "makers" gets populated as expected.
2. Select "models" is still disabled, as it should be.
3. I click on the "brands" select and see the available brands, as expected.
4. I select a brand and the following happens

- "brands" select doesn't show any value and if i click on it again, the list is empty
- the following warning appears

```
SelectInput.js:342 Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value
```

**Project setup**

```
let onChange = event => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE_USER_INVITE_FORM',
            field: event.target.id,
            payload: event.target.value
        });
    };

...
return(
...
<FormControl
    variant="outlined"
    className={classes.formControl}
    error={form.errors.brandId? true : false}
    disabled={brandRenderList.length < 0}>

    <InputLabel id="brand-label">Brand</InputLabel>
    <Select
        labelId="brand-label"
        id="brandId"
        label="Brand"
        value={form.brandIdId}
        onChange={(e) => { e.target.id = 'companyId'; onChange(e) }}
    >
        {brandRenderList}
    </Select>
    <FormHelperText>{form.errors.brandId}</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>

<FormControl
    variant="outlined"
    className={classes.formControl}
    error={form.errors.modelId? true : false}
    disabled={modelRenderList.length < 0}>

    <InputLabel id="model-label">Model</InputLabel>
    <Select
        labelId="model-label"
        id="modelId"
        label="Model"
        value={form.modelId}
        onChange={(e) => { e.target.id = 'modelId'; onChange(e) }}
    >
        {modelRenderList}
    </Select>
    <FormHelperText>{form.errors.modelId}</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
...
)
```

MyComponent.js

```
const selectedBrandId = useSelector(state => state.data.form.brandId);


// fetch brands
const brands = useSelector(state => state.brand.brands);

useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(brands).length === 0) {
        dispatch(getBrands())
    } else if (brandRenderList.length <= 0) {
        brands.brands.forEach(brand => {
            brandRenderList.push(<MenuItem value={brand._id} key={brand._id}>{brand.name}</MenuItem>)
        })
    }
}, [brands])


// fetch models
const models = useSelector(state => state.model.models);

useEffect(() => {
    if(!selectedBrandId ){return}
    else if (Object.keys(models).length === 0) {
        dispatch(getModels({brandId: selectedBrandId }))
    } else if (modelRenderList.length <= 0) {
        models.models.forEach(model => {
            modelRenderList.push(<MenuItem value={model._id} key={model._id}>{model.name}</MenuItem>)
        })
    }
}, [brands])
```

ParentComponent.js

If I put a static brandId, everything works just as desired. Obviously I want a dynamic one, which reacts to the user input in the brand select component.

```
// this works
const selectedBrandId = '6018f90b94a59215703adba0';

// this doesn't
const selectedBrandId = useSelector(state => state.data.form.brandId);
```

I appreciate any feedback :)

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? from reading your code the problem seems to be in your 'Brand' Select component....in the onChange you are passing 'CompanyId' instead of 'BrandId'...

Answer (score -1):

Hi mate i feel you i have been stuck for the same things few week ago at work !

I'm asking myself who had texted this nonsense warning alert: "You have provided an out-of-range value " you get this error just because the selectbox needs a defaultValue property. Insane bullsh** i agree and not really helpful for debug !

Hope you can fix it and keep coding have a great day !